# change div content with click, but stay on the page

Tags: javascript, visibility

I have the sitaution, that the primar topics in my menubar only contains instroductions, without any pictures. So I would prefer a solution, where by clicking on "about me" not a full site has to be loaded, though only the content of that one div changes, by fade out the first and fade in that one, which is the corresponding one, to the  element clicked.

Has there someone a solution for me, because my try to use the LUKGt/5/ jsfiddle  won't work, and there was all the time, every content showed.

Thx in before

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: put the code in the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .html([html content here[) method to replace the html content of a div.  On button/menu item click trigger a function that gets the information you want to load and use .html to overwrite the content in the desired div.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fgazfLaz/1/

html

```
<div id="content">
  Starting Content
</div>

<button type="button" id="changeContentBtn">Change div content</button>
```

Javascript

```
$("#changeContentBtn").click(function() {
  $("#content").html("Ending Content");
})
```